# Add jquery validation plugin to asp.net 4.5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I see that asp.net (framework 4.5) uses the

```
       <asp:ScriptReference>
```

tags to include the bundles for jquery and jqueryUI etc. 
But if i want to add a Jquery Validation plugin , how do i add that to my Site.Master page?

I cannot add it inside the  tags, because as at that point other main jquery scripts did not get added yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by reading about bundling and minification

Under the App_Start folder add the following to the BundleConfig.cs

```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryVal").Include(
                                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",);
```

Then in the Site.Master right after the end of ScriptReference Tags add the following

```
     <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
           <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryVal") %>
     </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

That worked for me.
I used this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx) for reference.